# Checking content of var located inside $.each() if json response before $.each() is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://v4p4sz5ijk.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/anbdata/states/notams/notams-list?format=json&api_key=90824210-70a2-11ea-9997-6943540cb84c&locations=opla", function(data) {

    //opst at the end of url points to an empty json file []. If opst is changed to opla then it points to a json file with data. 

    $.each(data, function(key, value) {

      var obj = value.Subject;

      if ($('obj').val() === '') {
        console.log("empty"); // with opst (json file with no data) this is expected but it is not shown.
      } else {
        console.log("not empty"); // with opla (json file with data) this is expected and it is shown correctly as expected.
      }

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Trying to check for content in a json file. If the json file has data then console.log displays "not empty" but if the json file has no data (i.e. it has only []) the console.log does not display "empty". The code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("url/test.json",function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key,value) {
            var obj = value.Subject;
            //  OPTION 1
            if(obj=="") {
                console.log("empty"); //This does not work
            } 
            else {
                console.log("not empty"); //This works
            }       
        });
    });
});
```

Other options I have tried are:

```
//  OPTION 2
if ($('obj').val() === '') { 
    console.log("empty"); //This does not work
} else {
    console.log("not empty"); //This works
}    

// OPTION 3
if(Object.keys(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object){
    console.log("empty"); //This does not work
} else {
    console.log("not empty"); //This works  
}
```

But the result is the same. Looks like I am making the same mistake in all cases. Need help in identifying the error. Thanks.

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` and add a [mcve] with example input and expected output

Comment: Even before `$.each(...)` you could check if the json is empty by doing `if($.isEmptyObject(data)) { console.log("Its empty") };` .No need to check key/value pairs.

Comment: Could you please share what is returned for `data` variable inside `$.getJSON`

Comment: @mplungjan code snippet added.

Comment: @ambianBeing Yes that is correct but need to know whats wrong with the if() after $.each(). It checks correctly if there is data but not when there is no data. palash it retuns []

Comment: @SpeckDrip Ok! if data is `[]` empty Array. the `$.each(data ...)` shouldn't even be executing since the `data []` doesn't contain any iterable value. Are you sure that.. the `$.each` in your case is executing and printing that `console.log("not empty");`?

Comment: @ambianBeing ok understood your point, so if $.each is not executing then is there something attributed to the var inside the function. Like in php var_dump would output string(0) "" or array(0) { } for an empty var/array. Does console.log give any output about a var inside $.each if it does not execute? $.each in my case is not printing console.log("not empty");

Comment: or since the execution of $.each is stopped the parser does not go further and console.log does not print anything.

Comment: Yeah! that is why I asked if you are getting any of the `console` prints for an `empty []` (which shouldn't be the case) as it was unclear from the question. Also didn't get exactly waht u asked in previous comment. if you are asking that `var obj = value.Subject;` be executed in an empty `array[] data` case, then no it won't.

Comment: Thanks got it! conceptual error at my end! Just a correction to my comment (since i can't edit now) regarding your question "$.each in my case is printing console.log("not empty");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the problem
Can't you just test the existance and length?

The each will not be executed at all if data does not have a length

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://v4p4sz5ijk.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/anbdata/states/notams/notams-list?format=json&api_key=90824210-70a2-11ea-9997-6943540cb84c&locations=opst", function(data) {

    //opst at the end of url points to an empty json file []. If opst is changed to opla then it points to a json file with data. 
    if (data === null || data && data.length === 0) {
      console.log("no data");
    } else {
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {

        var obj = value.Subject;

        if ($('obj').val() === '') {
          console.log("empty"); // with opst (json file with no data) this is expected but it is not shown.
        } else {
          console.log("not empty"); // with opla (json file with data) this is expected and it is shown correctly as expected.
        }

      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes it can be tested before $.each. I understand your point now that if data does not have a length then $.each is not executed. Then in this case, what is attributed to the var inside $.each? Shouldn't console.log give some output about that var?

Comment: Since the block itself of `$.each(data, function(key, value){...}` is going to be parsed **but not executed** in the case where the json response is empty, you are not going to get the console output too.

Answer (score 0):

so you can write utility function

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

then after the ajax call

```
if(data.isEmpty()) {
    console.log("empty");
} else {
     console.log("no empty");
}
```

Comment: Tried this before posting but no success. However, don't exactly understand the answer. Function is checking 'obj' and if() is checking 'data'. How do these two corelate.